# How match a complex string?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have to extract only this url out of a list 3-4 urls

> Url = http//:downloadXXX.megastuff.com/XXXXXXXXXXX

other urls belong to different domain.
for ex

> http//:zep.vipk.com/XXXx

I need to do this in android with

```
if (url.contains("http://www."))
{ then do something   }
```

Sorry if the question is noobish, I just started with java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [matches()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) to compare against a regex that matches URL's from the target domain, like:

```
if (url.matches("http\\://.*download.*\\.megastuff\\.com/.*") {
    //then do something
}
```